# How much yeast is in a "package"?

Tags: yeast, measurements

Our Better Homes and Gardens cookbook calls for "1 package active dry yeast" in its pizza recipe, which is less than helpful, since we keep a container of bulk yeast in the freezer. What is the standard volume (e.g. in teaspoons) of yeast in a package?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [Red Star](http://www.redstaryeast.com/tips-troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions), a very common yeast brand in the US:

> The strip contains three packets; each packet in the strip is considered one package.  Each package contains 1/4 oz. or 2 1/4 teaspoons of yeast.

This is approximately 7 grams, or 11 ml.

This is representative of all of the US brands.

Comment: 7g a sachet is standard in the UK, so it would seem to be somewhat standard

Comment: For dry yeast 1/4 oz seems to be the "standard", which is 7 g

Comment: Measuring by volume is unusual for dry substances in the metric system. In most countries using metric, the sachet will be labelled by grams, not milliliters.

Comment: @TFD: More like metric enemies, grrr... by the way, my sachets say 7g too.

Comment: 7g sachets are standard in Aus too.

Comment: TFD: Measuring by *ml* is unusual for dry substances, but tsp/dsp/tblsp common - not strictly metric of course, but commonplace within an otherwise metric recipe, and frankly more convenient (for small or fractional numbers) than 5/10/15ml.

Answer (score 0):

I just made cinnamon rolls and measured it out myself: 1 Packet of Yeast = 1 1/2 Tsp

This is Red Star instant yeast that I'm using.

Comment: I wonder why your measurement of 1¼ t differs so much from the 2¼ t that [Red Star states](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/43883/8569).

Comment: Specifying measurements in tablespoons is not much help, given  that these seem to differ everywhere.

Comment: @Colin -- Tsp = teaspoons or tablespoons?

Comment: My best guess is it means tablespoons (capital T often means that) but I guess it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: In US, T = [Tt]bsp = tablespoons, and t = [Tt]sp = teaspoons.

Answer (score 0):

As far as measuring yeast, I use instant yeast, rather than packets.  I have a Tupperware tub of year that's been in my freezer for about 15 years!  It shouldn't be viable, but it is.  The equivalent of 1 packet of yeast is 2 1/4 tsp.  Since my yeast is so old, I use 1 1/2 tbsp (sometimes more) and I get wonderful bread out of my almost 25-year-old bread machine.  I hope this helps.